# Creating separate layers from single CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, csv, import, split-by-attribute

I would like to add a single CSV file, which can then be separated within QGIS into separate layers.

[image]

With the aim of being able to turn off all layers except for 1 area that I am working on.

I understand that I can split this into 16 different CSV files to achieve my goal, however, with my text files that are much larger, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

I would probably follow this workflow :

**Step 1.** Add your CSV file via `Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer...`, check [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#importing-a-delimited-text-file) for more details.

**Step 2.** Apply the ["Split vector layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer) by `"Location"` field

Comment: Hi, 
I have followed your suggestion, now I am at the split vector layer. 
Split by location, I do not understand where the files go - I look in the log file to find the output in my temp. Find each indiviudal folder and it's output. But qGIS does not display any of the information in this output.

Comment: Which OS are you working on ? If it is WIndows check this root `C:/Users/username\AppData/Local/Temp/processing_***`, better see what the loggerof the algorithm tells.